# Pick then flatten a nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to build a generic function to be able to extract the property from an object with unlimited nested array.

**1st example**

```
var jsonObject= {
    level1 : [
        { id:123, level2 : [
                    {id:234, level3 : 'abc'},
                    {id:234, level3 : 'cde'}
                ]
        },
        { id:123, level2 : [
                    {id:234, level3 : 'efg'},
                    {id:234, level3 : 'ghk'}
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

extractProperty : 'level1.level2.level3' (the function should able to support unlimited level depends on this)

Expected Output (string) : 'abc,cde,efg,ghk'

**2nd example**

```
var jsonObject= {
    level1 : [
        { id:123, level2 : 'abc'},
        { id:123, level2 : 'cde'}
    ]
}
```

extractProperty : 'level1.level2'

Expected Output (string) : 'abc,cde'

Comment: There's no JSON in your question, you're just talking about objects.

Comment: well, you can say that.

Comment: btw, I am using lodash. So, the solution can make use of that too. thanks

Comment: Please do what every other programmer has done since the invention of computing. Think about how to solve the problem. That's called an "algorithm". Then write that down on a piece of paper in English. That's called "pseudo-code". Then turn your pseudo-code into a real computer program in the language of your choice. Then debug it. If you get stuck on some concrete problem along the way, I'm sure people here will be happy to help if you share with them what progress you've made and where you're stuck. Otherwise, find a programmer to write your programmer for you.

Comment: "*I want to…*" is all very well, but where is the question?

Comment: The question is how to write this 'generic function' obviously

Comment: Then your post should include something like "*I tried `<code>` with input `<data>`, expecting `<result>` but got `<other result/error>`*".

Comment: `the solution can make use of that too` - after you

Comment: How do you know I have put zero effort in it?

Comment: If stackoverflow is not a place to help solve coding issue, then I dont know what it is.

Comment: @Neo You could start off by reading existing guidance and materials about what SO is supposed to be, instead of just guessing, or imagining what you think it is supposed to be. Although there are some gray areas, there is a unanimous consensus that  it is not a code writing service. Stating this is not being "hurtful" or "refusing to be helpful"; it's just stating reality. Please be more aware of the distinction between "solve coding issues" and "writing code for me".

Comment: @torazaburo Totally valid reason. Yeah, so, please be more aware of the distinction between "solve coding issues" and "writing code for me". It's a totally good time to start thinking more about this exact sentence more next time before even answering. That will be a good start. :)

Comment: While some other like RobG gave some valid suggestion. I should have been more specific in the question.

Comment: The suggestions by RobG are just repeating existing, readily available information about the way to ask questions on SO that I'm sure you've already gone over in detail before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive solution for the two examples you gave. There could be some edge cases where it fails though.

```js
const jsonObject = {
    level1 : [
        { id:123, level2 : [
                    {id:234, level3 : 'abc'},
                    {id:234, level3 : 'cde'}
                ]
        },
        { id:123, level2 : [
                    {id:234, level3 : 'efg'},
                    {id:234, level3 : 'ghk'}
                ]
        }
    ]
};

function extractProperty(root, path) {
    return extractPropertyRecurse(root, path.split("."), 0).join(",");
}

function extractPropertyRecurse(root, levels, index) {
    if (Array.isArray(root)) {
        return [].concat(...root.map(x => extractPropertyRecurse(x, levels, index)));
    }
    
    const curr = root && levels[index] && root[levels[index]];
    if (curr) {
        return extractPropertyRecurse(curr, levels, index + 1)
    }
    
    return [root];
}

const results = extractProperty(jsonObject, "level1.level2.level3")
console.log(results);  // Out: "abc,cde,efg,ghk"
```

Comment: I like when people come together to help each other rather than questioning, criticizing and doubting each other. More time spent on helping than hurting each other. Good job, thank you. SO need more people like this.

Comment: @Neo I hardly think pointing out incorrect terminology is "doubting" each other, if that's what you're referring to. Actually, it **is** a way of helping each other. I hardly think pointing out basic protocols of using SO is "hurting" each other. Perhaps you could create some kind of "Stack Overflow Safe Space" where no one ever says anything that could even remotely be construed as critical, for people with self-esteem problems.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't find your first post on the question to be any help on how to use SO at all, nor it helps with the question. or perhaps we should have left SO for people with ego problem. :)

Comment: @Neo Sorry you feel that way. And sorry you seem to feel that SO is a place where you can find people to think for you, or teach you how to think. If you have a problem with people commenting on the goals of SO, or disagree with them, then I'm sure there are lots of sites, chatrooms, and helpdesks out there that would be a better fit.